# Fatal: git repository not found (but can go to URL) in Azure Devops?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops

It's on a fresh azure devops project.
I try to run Git Bash: "git clone (url)" and it says:

```
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier (name) does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository (url) not found
```

When I try to clone in visual studio code, same error.
I'm project leader so should have all permissions I presume? Also the fatal error says the URL wasn't found.

If I copy the url from this error & paste in into google, it can however find it...
What's up with that? Why can't I clone the url? Does anyone know a solution or possible check I can do?

Comment: The URL you are using might not be the correct one for cloning.

Comment: It's the one I get from Repo's -> Files -> Clone Repository in Azure Devops though.

Comment: Then you don't have permissions. Note that being admin does not automatically mean you have permissions to clone.

Comment: Where could I check this? Orginisation/project settings?

Comment: @fredrik what's weird is, I can however create a new branch etc on Devops... ?!

Comment: It's not wierd - it's the way DevOps is set up. The admin might not be a contributor. You will have to refer to the documentation on how to give yourself pull permissions

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Yes it was because I was logged in on Visual Studio using my personal account, but using the git credentials of my company. This will work if your personal account is NOT present in the entire organisation. In one case, this was also the case (because they didn't make my company e-mail fast enough so I already started working there and to access the code/repo, I just used my personal account for a week or so.) The solution was: add both accounts to the organisation and it won't fail on the personal account check, or just use 1 account e.g. your work account. It was an account mismatch issue :)

Comment: I have the same issue from a yaml pipeline, still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to navigate to the `Organization settings` -> `Permissions` -> `Project Collection Administrators` -> `Members` -> `Add` -> add your user account, and make sure you set the same user account in [Git Configuration](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) meanwhile.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not a valid solution for me, i was already in the Project Collection Administrators